# How to Find the Value of the Difference Quotient at x=3?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm confused on how to find the difference quotient of a number.

I started out by defining my function.

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] = (12 x)/(Sqrt[(x^2 - 5)])
```

Then I found the difference quotient

```
DifferenceQuotient[f[x], {x, h}]
```

I figured to find the difference quotient at x=3 I would just do

```
DifferenceQuotient[f[3], {x, h}]
```

but that just outputs 0 and I don't believe that is correct.

Comment: try : `DifferenceQuotient[f[x], {x, h}] /. x->3`

Comment: "that just outputs 0 and I don't believe that is correct." - what did you expect the difference quotient of a *constant* was going to evaluate to?

Comment: Following on the comment of @kglr, `DifferenceQuotient` will look in the first argument for the variable that you provide in the second argument.  Note that `f[3]` is not an expression in the variable `x`.

Comment: Note that `Limit[DifferenceQuotient[f[x], {x, h}] /. x -> 3, h -> 0] == f'[3]` evaluates to `True`